# JTextPane avoid blinking

Tags: refresh, jtextarea, focusable

I have a JTextArea and I want to disable blinking from it. I have tried to set focusable to false, but it doesn't seem to work. I also set editable to false and it doesn't work either. Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update**

`getCaret().setVisible()`doesn't seem to have any effect, at least with the Metal and Windows 7 L&Fs.

Here's two suggestions that might be enough for you, depending on what your final requirements:

1. Set the caret color to the same color as the `JTextField` background, effectively making it invisible.

   `myJTextField.setCaretColor(myJTextField.getBackground());`

   If you want to show the caret at a later time (say when the field gets focus), you could switch back to the original color (the documentation says passing a `null` will do that) when your `JTextField` gets focus.
2. Set the blink rate to 0 so even though the cursor will be visible, it won't be blinking.

   `myJTextField.getCaret().setBlinkRate(0);`

---

It seems like you want to hide the caret (the `|` cursor that indicates the current text insert position).

You can use `JTextField.getCaret().setVisible(false);`

Comment: I have tried that before, dude, but it seemed not to work. Thanks anyway

Comment: Sorry, you didn't mention what you'd already tried. And you're right - this doesn't work! See my updated answer for a couple other suggestions.

Comment: I will try the first later, thanks for the suggestions. I've already tried the second option and it didn't work.